# I want to install pango with cairo backend on windows 11, can anyone guide me?

Tags: cairo, msys2, windows-11, pango, pangocairo

I've looked at multiple posts on SO about how setting up pango or cairo is giving them errors and i tried setting it up a few times myself, but unfortunately there are just so many errors in the entire process that i decided to start from scratch, so anyone who's willing to help me out, i'd greatly appreciate it. I'm trying to create a build environment for a game, and pango is a prerequisite for it. Could someone guide me how I could get pango setup and working on my windows 11, or if its not possible, offer any helpful suggestions?